# Deleting conditional data from MySQL + Django

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a large pool of data, in a table specifically records counts are in millions, what I need to do is based on timestamp(field) I keep removing  data on monthly basis; this operation takes time in hours.

I must add that I have already done indexing on the timestamp field, and this application is working on Apache2 + md_wsgi + Django + MySQL stack.

Can there be any smart and effective way of doing this ?

Comment: How do you do it now?

Comment: @knbk Delete it using `delete` query with `where` clause.

Comment: Is it acceptable to delete the older data on a more frequent basis, say once per day? Deleting smaller chunks should significantly speed up the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try writing a simple bash script and put it in cron which can do all the deletion magic using plain SQL queries.

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password << END

DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `tm_field` >= 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

END
```

Since SQL queries are light-wighted in comparison to ORMs and deleting data in smaller chuck/frequently can help you greatly.